# SynEdit & RegEx search

Tags: regex, delphi, synedit

I'm looking for some example how to do regex search on SynEdit control in Delphi ?

I'd like to implement something like "grep" search in the current document ...

Comment: See the question about regex libraries for Delphi: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282749/best-delphi-regex-library. I would expect that using one of those libraries would be the same for the syntax editor as for any other blob of text, so can you please be more specific about what trouble you're having?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synedit comes with a builtin regex library and you can see an example search&replace application in the demos folder.